# What causes the performance issue of with_lock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec-rails

I'd like to understand what causes the performance impact.

I have a test in RSpec where a function was called 1000 times. I notice that as the for loop progresses, calls became slower and slower.

I nailed down the problem to be due to changing state inside a with_lock and outside of with_lock but can't explain why.

This is the smallest code to reproduces this issue (it only happens with RSpec, running it through a controller and browsing to a page containing the test doesn't produce the slowdown):

```
c = Conversation.new
c.save!

for i in 0..1000
    puts i
    c.with_lock do
        c.pending = true
        c.save!
    end
    c.pending = false
    c.save!
end
```

remove with_lock and no performance problem
don't have the outside c.pending = false / c.save! and no performance problem

Notice that there is only 1 entry in the database, not like we create tons of them.

PS: I found this because I DO have a slow down in production that I need to reproduce, BUT it only happens for users who have a huge amount of Conversation objects (and it happens because of the with_lock, which according to the database calls I see in my controller in developement are a straight commit using the primary key (no notion of user having more or less Conversation objects)). I'm thinking the reload performing automatically at the end of with_lock could "explain" that one since I have a "has_many :conversations, through: :xxxxxx" relationship on my User object. But I really can't explain where the performance issue comes from in test env (and not sure about prod either).

Comment: I'd experiment with how you've configured RSpec related to transactions. How is `use_transactional_fixtures` set? Are you using database_cleaner, and if so how is it set?